# Is this proof of $1\ne0$ in real numbers (set/field) valid?

Tags: solution-verification, real-numbers

I started reading spivak, just today, and on page 6 of the prologue. He states that it is not possible to prove that $1\ne0$ for the real numbers, with the basic properties of a ring.

But I got the following argument, for set real numbers particular case:

Assuming that $1=0$, it follows that $a(1)=a(0)$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$, where $a(1)=a$ and $a(0)=0$, Therefore $a=0$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Since there is $a≠0$ real, we have a contradiction. Q.E.D.

What was necessary that does not consist of the field axioms, would be to prove that:

$a(0)=0\quad$ (1)

and

$x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x=y$, then $ax=ay$, for $a \in \mathbb{R}$.  (2)

I also see that in this context, assuming that there is another real $a\ne0$, does not proceed. If my proof is incorrect, would it be because I can't show that there is another real $a\ne0$?

Comment: How do you decide that there is some $a\neq 0$?

Comment: To be clear also... you talk about "Since there is $a\neq 0$ **real**" why mention real numbers here?  We are talking about an arbitrary **R**ing and naming the **R**ing using the first letter of the word ring... **R**... which might or might not be the real numbers... and might or might not be the trivial ring with a single element.  The punchline is that the trivial ring with just a single element still satisfies all of the stated properties (*with the exception of $1\neq 0$*)

Comment: For the particular ring of the real numbers , proving $1\ne 0$ is like shooting rockets on ants. And every in any way interesting ring satisfies $1\ne 0$ , although this might be much more difficult to be proven in some rings.

Comment: Some of the confusion can be blamed on the somewhat ambivalently phrased "it is not possible to prove that $1\ne0$ for the real numbers, with the basic properties of the ring". Does that mean "it's not possible to prove that $1\ne0$ in *a general ring* (of which the real numbers are but one example) using only the basic properties of a ring?" in which case JMoravitz's comments apply. But the definition of *the real numbers specifically* contains way more information than just the ring properties, and from that information there are endless trivial proofs that $1\ne0$ as Peter comments.

Comment: I took a look https://isidore.co/CalibreLibrary/Spivak,%20Michael/Calculus%20(4th%20ed.)%20(8039)/ And he distinctly states " these properties would all hold if there were only one
number, namely, 0".   I think it is clear that Spivak is stating that the required condition to prove that $1 \ne 0$ is that we must add an axiom that there exists an $a\in R$ so that $a\ne 0$.

Comment: "There is $a\ne 0$" is not a basic property of the rings. You're supposed to use only the basic properties of the rings.

Comment: Hi @JMoravitz . Is the error in the assumption of the real other than zero? I see that assupposing doesn't mean it's true. But then what did spivak report that "it is not possible to prove that 1≠0 for the reals" (leading to us consider this as an axiom)? Or is there any valid proof for this one? (Ps. The **R** is for real numbers, not a ring. I am looking for real numbers particular case)

Comment: You are quoting him incorrectly.  He never mentioned the word "reals" in those paragraphs.

Comment: To rephrase what he is *actually* saying... he is saying that given a ring which satisfies all of the earlier mentioned properties (commutativity of addition, associativity of addition and multiplication, existence of "zero" the additive identity, existence of "one" the multiplicative identity, etc...) that these properties alone are not sufficient enough to prove that $1\neq 0$... that the ring which has only a single element in it, known in literature as "*the trivial ring*" still satisfies all of the necessary definitions to be known as a ring.

Comment: Indeed... if the only number in existence in our ring were zero... we *would* have that $a+b=b+a$ since $0+0=0+0$.... we *would* have that $a+(b+c) = (a+b)+c$ since $0+(0+0)=(0+0)+0$ and so on...  This ring is particularly boring however, and for that reason we often choose *not* to consider it.  It is common therefore to include in our ring definition or field definition etc... that $1\neq 0$ which makes the rings far more interesting... but again, the whole point is that you can not successfully prove that $1\neq 0$ using only the earlier mentioned ring properties.

Comment: Now... in the real numbers, of course $1\neq 0$, and of course there are real numbers which are nonzero... that was never in question.  Further, in the natural numbers and the integers, rationals, and so on... very clearly $1\neq 0$ simply because of the way that we have defined these number systems.  *However, he is here talking about arbitrary number systems*... not just the ones we are most familiar with.  He is *not* talking about the real numbers... he is merely talking about the concept of "number" in an abstract metaphorical sense.

Comment: @JMoravitz Now it seems clear to me. Thank you